# Django multi model best practice

Tags: python, django

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a multi-model django app where different models take advantage of the same views. For example I've got the models 'Car' 'Make' 'Model' etc and I want to build a single view to perform the same task for each, such as add, delete and edit, so I don't have to create a seperate view for add car, ass make etc. I've built a ModelForm and Model object for each and would want to create a blank object when adding and a pre-populated form object when editing (through the form instance arg), with objects being determined via url parameters.

Where I'm stuck is that I'm not sure what the best way to so this is. At the moment I'm using a load of if statements to return the desired object or form based on parameters I'm giving it, which get's a bit tricky when different forms need specifying and whether they need an instance or not. Although this seems to be far from the most efficient way of achieving this.

Django seems to have functions to cover most repetitive tasks, is there some magic I'm missing here?

edit - Here's an example of what I'm doing with the arguments I'm passing into the url:

```
def edit_object(request, object, id):
    if(object==car):
        form = carForm(instance = Car.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: What way are you doing this at the moment? A lot of IF statements may be required. You could just pass the model name in the URL e.g. `/delete/car/01 /delete/make/02` then you can have te

Comment: I am passing the model name into the url at the moment like you described, and using that for the if statements, I've added an example to the question.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)? Using CBVs is the best way in Django to make reusable code. For this example maybe it can be a little longer than function based views, but when the project grows up it makes the difference. Also remember "Explicit is better than implicit".

## urls.py

```
# Edit
url(r'^car/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EditCar.as_view(), name='edit-car'),
url(r'^make/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EditMake.as_view(), name='edit-make'),

# Delete
url(r'^car/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DeleteCar.as_view(), name='delete-car'),
url(r'^make/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DeleteMake.as_view(), name='delete-make'),
```

## views.py

```
class EditSomethingMixin(object):
    """Use Mixins to reuse common behavior"""
    template_name = 'template-edit.html'


class EditCar(EditSomethingMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Car
    form_class = CarForm


class EditMake(EditSomethingMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Make
    form_class = MakeForm


class DeleteSomethingMixin(object):
    """Use Mixins to reuse common behavior"""
    template_name = 'template-delete.html'


class DeleteCar(DeleteSomethingMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Car


class DeleteMake(DeleteSomethingMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Make
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your class and form as args to the method then call them in the code.

```
def edit_object(request, model_cls, model_form, id):
    form = model_form(instance = model_cls.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form':form})
```

then just pass in the correct classes and forms in your view methods

```
def edit_car(request,id):
    return edit_object(request, Car, CarForm, id)
```

each method knows what classes to pass, so you eliminate the if statements.

Comment: Thanks, sounds better than the if statements, but what I'm trying to achieve is just one edit_object view method which can be used for all objects. I realise this may be very difficult/impossible, but I want to make sure that is the case before I explore other avenues.

Comment: I don't understand - that method *is* one edit_object method that can be used for all classes. You can combine it with @akshar answer to pass in your args directly through a url, and it avoids using  edit_car() method as well.

Comment: Yes, the top one is, it's sort of what I'm doing now, calling one method from my views methods But then I'm still left with needing a view method for edit_car, edit_model and the rest that I'll have... and then a view method for add_car, add_model etc... what I ideally would like is just the one view method for each action that takes care of the relevant object based on what is passed in. If statements will work. Unless there's something I'm misunderstanding in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

## urls.py

```
url(r'^car/delete/(?<pk>\d+)/', edit, {'model': Car})
url(r'^make/delete/(?<pk>\d+)/', edit, {'model': Make})
```

## views.py

```
def edit(request, id, model):
    model.objects.get(id=id).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks man, passing the form in through the url sounds good. I am trying to define the model based on the (?P<obj>\d+) variable I'm passing. If statements seem to be the mosy obvious way, it just doesn't seem like the bes practice....

Comment: Tried that, I'm getting an error message saying url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'. I pretty much copied what you put above, and am sure that it all checks out, so I can't see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Edited the answer, it should have been a dict.